# node.js + express.io on centOS, bash command with no errors, no feedback

Tags: linux, node.js, bash, centos, express.io

My **nodeJs** script (/usr/bin/nodeapps/my/index.js):

```
app = require('express.io')();
app.http().io();
console.log("Ready!");

app.io.sockets.on('connection', function(s) {
    console.log("Utente connesso!");
    s.on('disconnect', function() {
        console.log('Utente disconnesso!');
    });
});


app.io.route('msg', function(req) {
    console.log(req.data.messaggio);
    app.io.sockets.emit('res', {
        data: req.data.messaggio
    });

});


app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('index.html')
});

app.get('/s', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('s.html')
});

app.listen(9000);
```

Dependencies (/usr/bin/nodeapps/my/package.json):

```
{
  "name": "socket-chat-example",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "my first socket.io app",
  "dependencies": {
      "coffee-script": "*",
      "express.io": "*",
      "connect": "*"
   }
}
```

node version (node --version):

```
v5.0.0
```

**The problem:**
when I run:

```
node index.js
```

or:

```
node index
```

The bash runs, but the express.io server doesn't start.
Only **console.log("Ready!");**

```
Ready!
```

and after 1 second the script stops and terminal show me a new line without any errors.

in Windows all works fine, the server starts and wait for connections.

Comment: It's working here, no problem at all.

Comment: [mmm]..any suggestion for me? in my local node.js server it's working, but  I want to use this script on this remote centOS machine...

Comment: start it with `node --debug index`

Comment: "Debugger listening on port 5858"...and if i send "cont" nothing happens. I haven't experience with debug